# is there a way to know all filters applied to one publication with query (SQL Server 2014)?

Tags: sql-server, replication

I'm looking for a way to get all filters applied to all my publication... I know that I can right click **properties** -> **Filter Rows** but is there a way to view them with a query?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38591859/finding-row-and-column-filters-in-transactional-replication

Comment: I couldn't find the table sysarticles...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the table **sysaticle** but if you don't find it, there is an alternative table **sysmergearticles** it has all the filters in column subset_filterclause.